# How to get transaction receipt?

Tags: transactions, history

If you use

```
cleos get block blocknum
```

you can only get the transaction data, but not the transaction receipt.

And in the transactions, there're some inline actions which we can't get through the blocks.

So, is it only possible to use history plugin to listen the specific actions?

I see that the history plugin can listen any inline actions you specified.

Answer (score 2):

**From eosjs module**

You can use [eosjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eosjs) node module to get tx status

```
 var txDetail = await eos.getTransaction(req.params.txid);
 console.log(txDetail.trx.receipt.status)
```

**From command line using cleos**

You can use `cleos` to get transaction details, and then use *trx.receipt.status* to check the status of your transaction

```
cleos get transaction txHash
```

Comment: but there is no transaction if you don't add the history plugin

Comment: Yes You need to start nodeos with --plugin eosio::history_api_plugin

Comment: not just history_api_plugin, but also history_plugin, and you must filter-on many actions

Answer (score 1):

I tried to find get receipt too but can't find anything related.
but int the path libraries/testing we can see a simple test.

```
 void base_tester::open() {
  control.reset( new controller(cfg) );
  control->startup();
  chain_transactions.clear();
  control->accepted_block.connect([this]( const block_state_ptr& block_state ){
    FC_ASSERT( block_state->block );
      for( const auto& receipt : block_state->block->transactions ) {
          if( receipt.trx.contains<packed_transaction>() ) {
              auto &pt = receipt.trx.get<packed_transaction>();
              chain_transactions[pt.get_transaction().id()] = receipt;
          } else {
              auto& id = receipt.trx.get<transaction_id_type>();
              chain_transactions[id] = receipt;
          }
      }
  })
```

we can get the receipt by id in chain_transaction.